# Show that $2^{k}w$ is an accumulation point of $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

**The problem**

Let $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a real-valued bounded sequence.
Assume $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(a_{2 n}-2 a_{n}\right)=0$
Assume $w$ is an accumulation point of the sequence $a_{n}$.

Given $k \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, show that $2^{k}w$ is an accumulation point of $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

**What I've tried**

Constructed $\phi(k) \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ strictly increasing.
Stated (given Epsilon > 0) for $N \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq N $ $\left|\left(a_{\phi(k)}\right)-w\right|<\varepsilon$

But I do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a_{2^{k}n} -2^{k}a_n \to 0$. Conclude that $|2^{k} w- a_{2^{k}n}|<\epsilon$ for infinitely many values of $n$ using the fact that $|w-a_n| <\epsilon$ for infinitely many values of $n$.

Comment: Hi Kavi , thank you for your answer. I do not quite understand how $a_{2^{k} n}-2^{k} a_{n} \rightarrow 0$ holds true

Comment: @Erik Dz  By iteration: $a_{4n}-4a_n=(a_{4n}-2a_{2n})+2(a_{2n}-2a_n) \to 0$. In the next step $a_{8n}-8a_n \to 0$ and so on.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. Apologies. Thank you very much